# Is there a way that I can have a word inside a label appear in a bold font?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I have this Xaml:

```
<StackLayout Spacing="0" Margin="20">
   <Label Text="I would like the word" />
   <Label Text="HERE"  />
   <Label Text="to be in a bold font and red color"  />
</StackLayout>
```

That gives this:

```
I would like the word
HERE
to be in a bold font
```

Is there some way I can combine these labels so that the word HERE appears in bold and red color and all words appear on one line? What I am looking for is this:

```
I would like the word HERE to be in a bold font
```

Note that I'm using Xamarin.Forms but I also tagged Xamarin.iOS as I would like to know if this is possible using a renderer and wonder if it can be done in iOS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`FormattedText`](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/label/#Formatted_Text)

```
<Label.FormattedText>
  <FormattedString>
     <Span Text="I would like the word " />
     <Span Text="HERE" ForegroundColor="Red" FontAttributes="Bold" />
     <Span Text="to be in a bold font" />
   </FormattedString>
</Label.FormattedText>
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer works very well.  I also opened another question as I realized that I would like to have this appear in a justified label.  Do you think this is possible?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46970713/is-there-a-way-that-i-can-use-spans-inside-of-a-label-and-also-have-it-justified

Comment: How can I set text value with binding viewmodel?

Comment: @ZiyadGodil : I guess I would either extend Span to support bindable text, or use a converter for `FormattedText`. Not sure why XF team kept the Text property on Span as simple property, instead of making it bindable.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Xamarin Forms you can use the [FontAttributes](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.FontAttributes/) style attribute.

```
<StackLayout Spacing="0" Margin="20">
   <Label Text="I would like the word" />
   <Label Text="HERE"  />
   <Label Text="to be in a bold font and red color"
          FontAttributes="Bold" />
</StackLayout>
```