# How to hyperlink part of a label text in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

In HTML5 I could accomplish this by doing something like:

```
lblTxt.Text = "For more info <a href='http://url.com1'>click here</a>, for contact <a href='mailto:contact@domain.com'>send an email</a>";
```

Tks

Comment: https://blog.pieeatingninjas.be/2017/11/05/creating-a-hyperlinklabel-in-xamarin-forms/

Comment: This plugin works perfectly https://github.com/matteobortolazzo/HtmlLabelPlugin

Answer (score 1):

Links are no first class citizen in Xamarin.Forms, due to its structure which is fundamentally different to HTML.

You could - if you insisted on links - create a `StackLayout` containing each one label for the text before and after the link and one for the link

```
<ContentPage ...>
   <ContentPage.Resources>
       <ResourceDictionary>
           <Style x:Key="LinkLabel" TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Blue" />
            </Style>
       </ResourceDictionary>
   </ContentPage.Resources>
   <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
       <Label Text="For more info" />
       <Label Text="click here" Style="{StaticResource LinkLabel}">
           <Label.GestureRecognizers>
               <!-- Add TapGestureRecognizer that invokes an action on your viewmodel -->
           </Label.GestureRecognizers>
       </Label>
       <Label Text=", for contact">
       <!-- and so on, I think you#ve got the gist -->
   </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Admittedly this does not scale very well, but it's conceivable to create a custom view based on a `ContentView` with a `Text` property that decomposes the text and adds the labels dynamically. This would work - technically.

**But**: Please don't do it, if you can avoid it at any rate. Texts with hypeterlinks are no native UI idiom. For the best UX you should stick to proven native UI idioms. Links may be hard to hit if the text is not large enough and - honestly - are most likely not the most beautiful option to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your code and insights. The problem is that the text before the link is rather long and it has multiple lines. when using a stack layout with Horizontal orientation does not concatenate the link with the text properly, like if it was in the same label. It looks like a grid with the text and the link in different cells.

Comment: [You can use the FormattedString property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46970713/is-there-a-way-that-i-can-use-spans-inside-of-a-label-and-also-have-it-justified) to give to your label an appearance of link keeping in mind that any part of the label would be 'clickable', but I completely agree with Paul on his concerns.

Comment: I also agree but that is how the business wants so... all I can do is advice.

Comment: Anyway I ended up with something like in the next post. Thanks for valueable help!

Answer (score 1):

**XAML Approach:**

```
<Label
    x:Name="LDescription"
    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
    TextColor="#000000">
    <Label.FormattedText>
        <FormattedString>
            <Span Text="We have so much to offer."/>
            <Span Text=" "/>
            <Span Text="Learn More." TextColor="#CF9F24">
                <Span.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Command}" NumberOfTapsRequired="1"/>
                </Span.GestureRecognizers>
            </Span>
        </FormattedString>
    </Label.FormattedText>
 </Label>
```

**Code Behind Approach:**

XAML

```
<Label
    x:Name="LDescription"
    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
    TextColor="#000000">
    <Label.FormattedText>
        <FormattedString>
            <Span Text="We have so much to offer."/>
            <Span Text=" "/>
            <Span x:Name="SLearnMore" Text="Learn More." TextColor="#CF9F24"/>
        </FormattedString>
    </Label.FormattedText>
 </Label>
```

Code Behind

```
YourPage() //constructor
{
    Appearing += YourPage_Appearing;
    Disappearing += YourPage_Disappearing;
}

void YourPage_Appearing(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var learnMore = new TapGestureRecognizer();
    learnMore.Tapped += LearnMore_Tapped;
    SLearnMore.GestureRecognizers.Add(learnMore);
}

void YourPage_Disappearing(object sender EventArgs e)
{
    SLearnMore.GestureRecognizers.Clear();
}

void LearnMore_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Your click logic    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With your ideas I ended up with this code:

```
<Label>
<Label.FormattedText>
    <FormattedString>
        <Span Text="long bla bla bla..., "/>
        <Span Text="click here" ForegroundColor="Blue"/>
        <Span Text=" and more bla bla"/>
    </FormattedString>
</Label.FormattedText>
<Label.GestureRecognizers>
    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding ClickHereCommand}" NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
</Label.GestureRecognizers>
</Label>
```

Comment: the downsides are: I cannot use bindings so... no MVVM and the whole label triggers the event and not just the click me part

Comment: Why not just put the gesture recognizer on the Span?